# Python Add Key to Dict conditionally

Tags: python, dictionary, insert, key

I'm trying to generate a dict from a list of headers that "associates" columns of data to the same experiment. For example, I want to turn:

```
headers = ["A_1","A_2","A_3","B_1","B_2","B_3"]
```

into

```
cols = { 1 : {'A' : 0, 'B' : 3}, 2: {'A' : 1, 'B' : 5} ... }
```

My code is as follows:

```
cols = {}
headers = ["A_1","A_2","A_3","B_1","B_2","B_3"]

col_number = 0
for header in headers:
   run_number = header[-1:]
   cols[ run_number ] = {}

   if "A_" in header:
      cols[ run_number ][ 'A' ] = col_number
   if "B_" in header:
      cols[ run_number ][ 'B' ] = col_number

   col_number += 1
print cols
```

This Outputs only the last "B" columns:

```
{'1': {'B':3}, '2':{'B':5}... }
```

HOWEVER, if I try a simple experiment at the command shell, this notation seems to work well...

```
cols = {}
cols[1] = {}
cols[1]['A'] = 1
cols[1]['B'] = 2
print cols

>> {'1' : {'A':1,'B':2} }
```

why?

**EDIT:** 
Just needed another set of eyes I guess. The issue was this line in the loop...

```
    cols[ run_number ] = {}
```

It overwrites cols[ run_number ] to an empty dict every time a column from a pre-existing run_number is reached.

Comment: Are you sure that last segment worked for you? You assigned a key of `1` with a value of an empty `list`, but then you try to add to that `list` with dictionary notation. The output also seems fake, as it turned the integer key `1` into the string `'1'`.

Comment: Whats the values in dict `{'A' : 1, 'B' : 5}` ? are they indices? if yes why not `B:4` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is overwriting this important variable and setting it to an empty dict:

```
cols[ run_number ] = {}
```

This means it gets through the "A_" strings for the various numbers and then when it's onto the "B_" strings, it overwrites all the `run_number` keys it already created for the "A_" strings.

You should try something like the following instead:

```
if run_number not in cols:
   cols[ run_number ] = {}
```

Alternately, you could try to use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html)

Comment: Thanks. Dumb question in retrospect.

Comment: I don't know if I agree. It takes awhile to build up a mental model of what the interpreter is doing so that when you read some code you have in mind all the variables' values. If you're still learning, something like this tool can help with that (especially for recursion): http://www.pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should change to the following line of codes:

```
 if run_number not in cols:
     cols[ run_number ] = {}
```

I tested, the following code works:

```
for header in headers:
   run_number = header[-1:]
   if run_number not in cols:
      cols[ run_number ] = {}
   if "A_" in header:
      cols[ run_number ][ 'A' ] = col_number
   if "B_" in header:
      cols[ run_number ][ 'B' ] = col_number
   col_number += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use `enumerate()` to have Python automatically keep track of counting.  Second, as others said, you are overwriting your dictionary keys with a new one instead of adding to the existing dictionary.

Something like following should work for your case:

```
cols = {}   
for col, header in enumerate(headers):
    typ, _, key = header.partition('_')
    if key not in cols:
        cols[key] = {}
    cols[key][typ] = col
```

With your data, `cols` is:

```
{'1': {'A': 0, 'B': 3}, '2': {'A': 1, 'B': 4}, '3': {'A': 2, 'B': 5}}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Because the "run_number" variable repeats, every time you loop and it repeats, you overwrite it with any empty dict.
2. Below is a way to accomplish your objective.

   ```
   def answer():
       headers = ["A_1","A_2","A_3","B_1","B_2","B_3"]
       cols = {}
       cols[1] = {}
       cols[2] = {}
       cols[3] = {}
       for header in headers:
           cols[int(header[-1:])][str(header[:-1])] = headers.index(header)

       return cols

   print answer()
   ```